# Java Programmatically send GraphQL REST Query

Tags: json, scala, playframework, graphql

I'm new to GraphQL and I'm trying to figure out how can I programmatically send a GraphQL POST query that I have implemented in a separate micro-service.

In my main application I'm using Java + Spring REST Template to send the query while attaching the POST Body as a String GraphQL query e.g.

```
String body = "query MyLearner {learner(id: 1) {lastName givenName} learners { givenName }}";
```

I can receive the query in my play-scala micro-service but can't parse the JSON.

Receiving method:

```
def graphqlBody(tenant: Int) = Action.async(parse.json) { request ⇒
    val query = (request.body \ "query").as[String]
    val operation = (request.body \ "operationName").asOpt[String]

    val variables = (request.body \ "variables").toOption.flatMap {
      case JsString(vars) ⇒ Some(parseVariables(vars))
      case obj: JsObject ⇒ Some(obj)
      case _ ⇒ None
    }

    executeQuery(query, variables, operation)
}
```

Note I've basically tried to implement the GraphQL Sangria code with my domain model so it might look similar to people. [sangria](https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria)

Im getting an error on line 1 of the method while parsing the JSON I'm assuming it's because the JSON body coming in isn't valid JSON because it's in GraphQL format but this is what is used and works for Sangria so not sure why it wouldn't work here.

> play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[JsResultException: JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List("query MyLearner {learner(id: 1) {lastName givenName} learners { givenName }}" is not an object),WrappedArray())))))]]

Screenshot from debug of JSON received JSON Body:[image]

Thanks to @Ra Ka guidance I was able to come out with the correct query please see below for answer:

```
{  
   "variables":{  
      "id":1
   },
   "operationName":"MyLearner",
   "query":"query MyLearner($id: Long!) {learner(id: $id) {misId givenName}}"
}
```

Comment: what is the body of the request that the method receives ? As you said it seems like play fails to decode your json

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot of the JSON Body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are providing graphql query in wrong format. The actual `graphql` query is not a valid `JSON` format  and you are providing in that format and hence you will definitely get invalid JSON exception. Therefore you need to provide `graphql` query as value instead of body. As your receiving method is parsing `query`, `opertionName` and `variables` field, you need to provide request body in following format:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "id": "123"
    },
    "operationName":"MyLearner",
    "query": "query MyLearner {learner($id: String) {lastName givenName} learners { givenName }}"
}
```

If you want to learn more about query such as variables and operationName please refer [here](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/)

In addition, when I learned graphql, I have trouble understanding operationName and if you know about it, ignore this. OperationName is used to to select from multiple query that you already have in `query` field. For example:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "id": "123"
    },
    "operationName":"Query1" or "Query2" //provide either of query to get data so that you can write single query for all data fetching and provide operationName for each type of data,
    "query": "query Query1 {learner($id: String) {lastName givenName} learners { givenName }} query Query2 {learner($id: String) learners { givenName }}"
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude I wasn't able to clearly make this out from the tutorials I was following. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Hey @Ra Ka there is a few small errors with your answer but I was able to figure them out. Ill update my post with the answer if you want to update your answer to be similar to mine as you deserve majority of the credit.